# How to use more than one event handler for a function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I combine more than one Event Handler,

```
document.getElementById("prix").onchange = function(e)
{
document.getElementById("hhh").innerHTML = this.value*100;
};
document.getElementById("prix").onkeyup = function(e)
{
document.getElementById("hhh").innerHTML = this.value*100;
};
```

I know this is horrible if I do this, so how can I combine them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define the function and use it twice

```
var handler = function (e) { 
  document.getElementById("hhh").innerHTML = this.value*100;
};

document.getElementById("prix").onchange = handler;
document.getElementById("prix").onkeyup = handler;
```

Comment: got it :p
thank you :)
NB: cant accept the answer before 12 minutes